# Is JSON array parsable? (Stream parser)

Tags: javascript, json, yql

I have a YQL query that extracts data from a page and returns it to my script as JSON. The JSON is huge, and as such, here's my question:

Is JSON array parsable? So that I can iterate over the entire JSON structure?

Comment: Ofcourse json is parsable. How else would anyone use it :)?

Comment: I suggest clarifying that you want to have a stream parser, rather than parsing the entire structure in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON per definition is parsable - it is JAVASCRIPT. The question is moe how much code that neeeds, which may depend on the specific JSON array (how little can you get away with).

If JSON would not be parsable in principle, it would be totally worthless, you know.